# Mysql compare IP address from table

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

I have a query in which i wanted to compare the ip address of system with the existed ip in records of table. but not able to compare the ip .. when i use normal query for counting records it works but not with Ip address in Where clause.
my query is as below

```
SELECT count(product_id) AS count_likes, product_count FROM 
'._DB_PREFIX_.'count_likes WHERE product_id = '.$product_id.' AND ip-address =
"'.trim($ip_address).'";
```

I just want o compare ip and count no of matching records.

Comment: is your column really named `ip-address`? if so, you have to put it in backticks.

Comment: yes column name is same as i taken in query ip-address

Comment: An IP address is a binary piece of data and can be encoded in many different ways. If you compare different representations of the same data you won't get matches as expected. You first need to determine the format and contents of the MySQL column (any decent MySQL client will allow that) and `$ip_address` (for which you can use e.g. `var_dump()`). Please gather that information and update your question.

Comment: Ok thanks for suggestion ... i will do same

Answer (score -1):

so far i got a just small mistake, So would like to post here

below is my modified query

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'count_likes WHERE `product_id` = 
"'.$product_id.'" AND `ip_address` = "'.$ip_address.'"';
```

It has back quote difference to the column name ... Thanks to all for reply.